# Nyaya-like works by Vaishnavas

Tags: vaishnavism, nyaya

Are there any Nyaya works written by Vaishnavas or Vaishnava works like Nyaya with rational inquiry? I know Chaitanya Mahaprabhu had been born close to Nyayaikas he must have had a work syncretizing his thoughts with Vaishnavism. What about Nyaya commentaries on Bhagavad Gita or vedantic works?